# Car has a vibration when driven more than 120km/h

Tags: opel, corsa

I use opel corsa CDi 1.4.

I was able to drive more than 160km/h but lately it’s hard to drive more than 120km/h.

Steer begins to shake after 120km/h and goes to even 140km/h.

What could be the problem?

Comment: When was the last time you had a wheel balance done? Also check if a tyre is low on air.

Comment: It does sound like you have lost one of the weights that balance your wheels.  Get the wheels re-balanced.

Comment: A steering joint loose? When did you last have a decent service?

Comment: Can you describe the vibration more.  Does it come through the steering wheel or do you feel it through the seat?  When was the car last serviced?  A partially blocked fuel filter could cause this type of behaviour.  Typically wheel balance issues can be driven though.

Comment: And tire balance may not fix defective tires; I had a set balanced three times ( on a recently purchased used car ) . The tires would be good for a week or so ,then  begin vibration again ( at speed).

Comment: I noticed there was bump on the left front tire. I’ve got it replaced. The vibration has stopped. I’ve not driven passed 120km/h though.